# sum the case expression with aggregate function

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008

In one of my application I want to sum the case expression with aggregate function.

I have tried the following query

```
Select Name,Sum(Case When MIN(arrival_time) = MAX(arrival_time) then 1 Else 0 End) as arrivedate from TableName group by Name
```

But I got an error like this.

```
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Please figure out my problem.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not have aggregation function in aggregation function, which means you can not do

```
sum(min(..) )
```

try:

```
select Name,Sum(Val) as arrivedate 
from (
    SELECT name , (Case When MIN(arrival_time) = MAX(arrival_time) then 1 Else 0 END) Val
    FROM TableName
    group by Name
) x
group by Name
```

but, do you really need the SUM ? I feel like:

```
SELECT name , (Case When MIN(arrival_time) = MAX(arrival_time) then 1 Else 0 END) Val
FROM TableName
group by Name
```

will give you the same result any way, for that the inner query and outer query all group on Name

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    Name, 
    Sum(Case When MN = MX then 1 Else 0 End) arrivedate
from(
    select Name, Min(arrival_time) MN, max(arrival_time) MX From TableName
    group by Name
)x
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a sum (which goes across multiple records) of the min and max values which also goes across the records. You would need to redo the query where you get the the min/max first and then do the sum statement checking them.